# Слова "сад" и "садить" однокоренные?

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор

Готовлю задания для учеников по составу слова и словообразованию. В многочисленных учебниках и пособиях авторы связывают родством слова "сад" и "садить" (и это совершенно логично). В словаре Тихонова эти слова являются вершинами разных словообразовательных гнёзд, а значит, не являются родственными. Как мне следует поступить: идти за учебниками или прикрываться Тихоновым?

Comment: Схожее явление:
яблоко и яблоня,
добро и добреть,
война и воевать. Слова в этих парах также не являются друг другу родственными.

Comment: Ну так виделось дериватологу Тихонову словообразование, с "гнёздами" и "звёздами"; у него и "подсолнух" не имеет однокоренных слов.

Answer (score 2):

За учебниками, конечно! Тихонов во многом плох и необъясним, но даже если отбросить это, детям и вообще носителям легко осознать, что сад — это место, куда по**садили** растения. Связь между словами жива.

Answer (score 2):

[**САДИТЬ** *прост.* то же, что сажать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) - лучше не обучать, а отучать деток от просторечий, мол, не комильфо.

Но если выбирать, то, конечно, школьные учебники.

---

[Однокоренные слова к слову «сад»](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sostav-slova/koren/odnokorennyie-slova-k-slovu-sad.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Садить или сажать: как правильно?](http://newslab.ru/article/187506)

> Накануне посевной кампании наша читательница поинтересовалась:
> картошку «садят» или «сажают»? А и правда, в чём разница между
> глаголами **«садить»** и **«сажать»**, насколько она существенна?
>
> Древнерусский глагол *«садити»* имеет, с одной стороны, общий корень с
> древнеиндийским *sadayati* «сажает», а с другой – с готским *satjan*
> «сажать». Выходит, что неопределённость с буквой в корне наблюдается
> уже на протяжении многих веков.
>
> Тем не менее, лингвисты определяют между ними значительную разницу. В
> современном русском языке приоритет имеет глагол **«сажать»**,
> практически во всех значениях. **«Садить»** ***считается
> снижено-разговорным словом***, что, впрочем, было не всегда. В словаре
> Даля оба слова упоминаются как синонимы, с одной лишь оговоркой:
> «садить» употребляется для обозначения более решительного действия.
>
> Также, в случае, когда речь идёт о растениях, чаще употребляется
> ***глагол «садить», что, видимо, связано с родственным словом «сад»***. Если же герои повествования – люди, то используется
> **«сажать»**. *Фабрика – это не хлеб сеять, не картошку садить* (М. Горький). *Я говорила, что на крышу нельзя сажать пассажиров, –
> кричала по-английски девочка, – вот подбирай!* (Л. Толстой). Слово
> «сажа», кстати, родственно глаголу «сажать», поскольку означает «то,
> что насело».
>
> Резюмирую: согласно современным словарям, правильно говорить и писать
> «сажать картошку» (репу, капусту и так далее). Тем не менее, не
> исключён и вариант «садить картошку», но нужно помнить, что он носит
> просторечный характер, хотя всего сто лет назад был вполне
> литературным.

Comment: Ну ладно, не верил Тихонов утверждению "сама садик я садила", а как у него по "лексическим гнёздам" при "звёздах" раскладывалось "пружение прудов"? И не роднятся ли у него сады с известным маркизом?

Comment: Галина, несколько замечаний: 1) «детки» гораздо лучше (видимо) поймут связь между садить и сад, чем между сажать и сад. Поэтому почему бы и не использовать это слово? Объяснить попутно, что так не пишут, но говорят — и всё. 2) Вы привели какую-то ужасную статью в конце. Автор плохо понимает предмет своих изысканий: «Выходит, что неопределённость с буквой в корне наблюдается уже на протяжении многих веков» — это заключение вообще никак не проистекает из различий между санскритом и готским...

Comment: И да, у вас эксплицитно ответ не выражен. Может, исправите?

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое эксплицитно выраженный ответ. Про связь *сад - садить* изложено в пункте два, где развесистая клюква отображена. Зачем «деткам» вообще знать о существовании уродливой формы "садить"?! Пусть, как и положено, считают фольклорно-народно-поэтическим при случайной встрече. Об авторе статьи ничего не могу сказать: взялся публично пересказывать историю глаголов, наши позиции в тихой ненависти к "садить" совпадают, а что там не так в теории - об том судить не могу: практик мы.

Comment: "Имплицитная («скрытая, неявная») логика - есть свойство представлять свои рассуждения в такой форме, что логическая их структура не бросается в глаза, не очевидна. Это не говорит о том, что тезисы имплицитного логика противоречивы. Общее ощущение от продукта мыслительной деятельности имплицитного логика - это такой дикий сад, по которому садовод прошелся в неком трансе, разбрасывая семена как бог на душу положит. Удивительным образом вырастает нечто небессмысленное, в каком-то смысле, целостное и даже - это эксплицитному логику совсем непонятно - содержательное".